# Android calling same layout for - layout for nexus 1 and nexus 5 but display different design

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I developed one app, that have following layout screen,

```
layout
layout-large
layout-xlarge
```

but for nexus one and nexus five calling same only 'layout' folder , but both phone display different things for same design, like if i adjust screen as nexus five then nexus one affected, as vice versa,

So, how can i prepare Screen for both ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you add support all screens code in manifest.xml?

Comment: And also please avoid using layout-large or layout-xlarge kind of folders as it was deprecated in API 13 and above. Please go through following link for more understanding about supporting different screen sizes! http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Cant say anything blindly why its happening if you can show what you are doing? And show some code of your layout we can help.

Answer (score 3):

- Use dp instead of px
- Use Relativelayout and LinearLayout, and weight if necessary
- you can add a layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi, etc. to get different
  layouts for such devices (nexus 1, 5, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you added this in your manifest.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

And also try avoid using layout-large and layout-xlarge as it was deprecated in API 13. [See this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more understanding for supporting multiple screen sizes

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html   , in this document , describe folder as i created if it deprecated from the api 13., as  res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation

Comment: can i use layout-sw320dp
layout-sw480dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp  instead of that ?

Comment: Yes u need to change them. Its is the preferred approach!

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
layout
layout-large
layout-xlarge
```

to

```
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw480dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
```

- 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800
  hdpi, etc).
- 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
- 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
- 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280    mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).